# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property (variable declaration)

Tags: c#, variables, sqlconnection

I am trying to add a parameter to my query and upon doing so it gives me the above error. I have the variable public I declare outside or my method. I tried making it static as I have read on other posts but it then it gives me the errors every else its referenced. The Method I am working in a public static list method.

Steps taken:
Tried declaring a variable in my method t pass the variable to.
Online research
Tested online research.

Here is my declared variable:

```
public int CarrierID { get; set; }
```

Here is my method where I am attempting to add the parameters and where it gives me the error at CarrierID cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CarrierID", **CarrierID**); :

```
SqlConnection dbConn = new 
   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
   ["Connection"].ConnectionString);

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = sqlString.ToString();
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CarrierID", CarrierID);

   SqlDataReader reader = null;

   try
   {
      reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null);
      if (reader != null)
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
              EmpData ed = new EmpData();
              ed.CarrierID = (int)reader["CarrierID"];
              list.Add(ed);
           }
```

empData class:

```
class EmpData
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public static int CarrierID { get; set; }
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string CarrierName { get; set; }


    public static List<EmpData> getData()
    {

        List<EmpData> list = new List<EmpData>();

        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        sqlString.Append("SELECT e.*, c.Carrier ");
        sqlString.Append("FROM Employee e, CellCarrier c ");
        sqlString.Append(" WHERE e.CarrierID = @CarrierID ");
        sqlString.Append("  AND e.CarrierID = c.CarrierID");

        SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlString.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CarrierID", CarrierID);

        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            reader = DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null);
            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    EmpData ed = new EmpData();
                    ed.EmployeeID = (int)reader["EmployeeID"];
                    ed.FName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    ed.LName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                    ed.UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                    ed.Password = reader["Password"].ToString();
                    ed.Email = reader["Email"].ToString();
                    ed.CarrierID = (int)reader["CarrierID"];
                    ed.CellNumber = reader["CellNumber"].ToString();
                    ed.IsActive = (bool)reader["IsActive"];
                    ed.CarrierName = reader["Carrier"].ToString();
                    list.Add(ed);
                }
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
                dbConn.Close();
                dbConn.Dispose();
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("No records returned");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dbConn != null)
            {
                try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                try { reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused - is `CarrierID` an _input_ or _output_?  If it's an input, where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: You are confusing `variables` and `properties`. You have created a property, not a variable - it makes the question very confusing to understand, as it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @rb try that I edited it.

Comment: You must make sure you dispose of your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`  - perhaps you have `.Dispose()` calls for each at the end of your code already? - or wrap them in `using` statements which ensure they are properly disposed.

Comment: @stuartd it's there I just didn't post.

Comment: Is the method where you are adding the parameters `static` or not?

Comment: I just edited with my entire class.

Comment: `public static List<EmpData> getData()` is your problem.  Is there are reason why this method is static?

Comment: @paqogomez use it as an array in my form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is `static`.. your variable is not.

You need to mark your variable as `static` for it to be used in `static` methods:

```
public static int CarrierID { get; set; }
//     ^^^^^^ this
```

The other option you have is to remove the `static` modifier from the method this code is in and instantiate the class it is in before using it.

EDIT:

After your edit.. I think you should change your method to this:

```
public static List<EmpData> GetData(int carrierId) {
    // code here..

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CarrierID", carrierId);

    // code here..
}
```

Then, whenever you call it.. pass in the `CarrierID` you need:

```
EmpData.GetData(5);
```

I assume you already have the required `CarrierID` available and set.. prior to calling this method (so you can pass it in). I also uppercased the first character of the method.. since that is more in line with C# style.

Comment: I didnt downvote.. but he does say.. "I tried making it static as I have read on other posts but it then it gives me the errors every else its referenced."

Comment: @SimonWhitehead hey I edited hopefully its clearer. I tried making it public static then it says: Error 1 Member 'CBJDataEditingSoftware.EmpData.CarrierID.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Can you show us your actual class with this method in it? Currently it is unclear whether this method is part of the `EmpData` class or not, or the property `CarrierID` for that matter.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I have posted the entire class where the problem is which is in empData

Comment: @paqogomez your quote by the OP is fine but it's just misguided, ofc it gives you errors everywhere you call `MyInstance.ThisIsNowAStaticMethod()`, that doesn't mean the method shouldn't be static, it just means he needs to make corrections elsewhere in order for it to work.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos I have made an edit with a suggested fix.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead would that mess up the rest of my fields I'm getting from that reader?

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos Not at all. It doesn't change how your method works. It just changes how you call it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead now there is a new issue. I call the method twice once for filling one combobox and another time for my second combobox.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead it clears my list though so can I just use separate values for them?

Comment: Store the result of the first call in a list. Then use that list for your second combobox. Without seeing the rest of your code thats the best I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. Thanks for including your full class. You are trying to use your CarrierID for two purposes -- once to seed your query, and once to store the CarrierID for an EmpData instance. It can't be both. I think what you're trying to do would be best accomplished with a parameter:

```
public static List<EmpData> getData(int carrierID)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{

    List<EmpData> list = new List<EmpData>();

    StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
    sqlString.Append("SELECT e.*, c.Carrier ");
    sqlString.Append("FROM Employee e, CellCarrier c ");
    sqlString.Append(" WHERE e.CarrierID = @CarrierID ");
    sqlString.Append("  AND e.CarrierID = c.CarrierID");

    SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = sqlString.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CarrierID", carrierID);
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Suggestion: Edit your other answer.

Comment: Nah. I just deleted it instead. It's no longer applicable now that the OP has changed his question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is an instance variable and you're using it like a static one. So there are three options, the first is to make it a static variable (keep in mind all instances have the same value if that is the case). The option option is to access it from an instance so say it belongs to a class called `Carrier` then you would need something like;

```
    Carrier c = new Carrier();
    // anywhere within the same scope as the line above
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CarrierID", c.CarrierID);
```

And lastly, you could make it so the method is an instance method in which case you wouldn't get this error when accessing instance variables.

Answer (score -5):

Parameters should start with the @ sign.

try 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierID", CarrierID);